# Why do the MDN DOM pages not show properties being on the object's prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

On MDN the properties of DOM objects are shown to be [directly on the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) itself, as opposed to on its prototype, like it does with other built-in types (examples: [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)).

When I define a new DOM object (e.g. `const myEle = document.createElement('div');`), and inspect it, I can see it is prototype linked all the way up to `Object` then `null`.

How come MDN does not show the properties as being on `Element.prototype` etc?

Comment: writting Object.keys(myEle) I get an empty array and when i write I saw all properties myEle.__proto__ so it is in the prototype. MDN don't tell if it is in the proto or not it only tell which property is accessible

Comment: Maybe so the articles end up with URLs like `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes` instead of URLs like `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prototype/attributes`. So it’s just a documentation convention and not meant to indicate how you’d actually access the properties from code; instead the code examples in the articles show how you’d normally do that — which generally is by creating an instance and accessing the properties of the instance: for example, `var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var atts = para.attributes`.